# Change color of window frame

Tags: android

How do I go about changing the color of the frame of this dialog? I've tried a bunch of things and nothing works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="CustomDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">               
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: @Alex Volovoy: I just want to set the border of the dialog window to a different color. There's no attribute for that? Such as, android:frameColor or anything? That would be too easy of course. :)

Comment: Also take a look at this (concerning "nine-patch" images): http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You mean white frame ? I think it's a part of 9-patch drawable you can look up how Theme.Dialog is build in the SDK_FOLDER\platforms\android-sdkversion\data\res\values
and then styles.xml and themes.xml

As i've said, the white frame is a part of the background image. its panel_background.9.png So if you want to change frame - you'll need different background image + need to overwrite in style setting it.

```
 <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:drawable/panel_background</item>
```

and you'll need to define a style that will be derived from Theme.Dialog and have this

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/your_drawable</item>
```

so if you put in styles.xml something like

```
<style name="NewBorderDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
 <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/your_drawable</item> 
</style>
```

Put new drawable and set your activity to the new theme - you should see your new border

Comment: It's not working for me, it just displays the image behind the untempered dialog. What am I missing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310412/progressdialog-nesting-inside-of-another-blank-dialog

Comment: That's incorrect, that will only change the background of the underlying window.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it Programatically, try below code:

**What you have to do:**

> When `AlertDialog` is visible on your screen, `OnShowListener` is called. So, by adding `dialog.setOnShowListener(this)` you will be able to customize your `AlertDialog`.

**Code:**

```
// Create AlertDialog
AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(context1);
    adb.setTitle(context1.getString(R.string.app_name))
    .setMessage(message)
    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
});
AlertDialog dialog = adb.create();

// Make some UI changes for AlertDialog
dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
    @Override
    public void onShow(final DialogInterface dialog) {

        // Add or create your own background drawable for AlertDialog window
        Window view = ((AlertDialog)dialog).getWindow();
        view.setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.your_drawable);

        // Customize POSITIVE, NEGATIVE and NEUTRAL buttons.
        Button positiveButton = ((AlertDialog)dialog).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        positiveButton.setTextColor(context1.getResources().getColor(R.color.primaryColor));
        positiveButton.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        positiveButton.invalidate();

        Button negativeButton = ((AlertDialog)dialog).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
        negativeButton.setTextColor(context1.getResources().getColor(R.color.primaryColor));
        negativeButton.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        negativeButton.invalidate();

        Button neutralButton = ((AlertDialog)dialog).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);
        neutralButton.setTextColor(context1.getResources().getColor(R.color.primaryColor));
        neutralButton.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        neutralButton.invalidate();
    }
});
```