# How to change border color of dialog?

Tags: android

I have created a custom dialog. It is having default border color as white.
How can I change it's border color?

Comment: You can sustom like http://www.anddev.org/custom_theme_dialog___transparent_background-t7300.html

Answer (score 0):

Write your own theme (based on the dialog theme) and set the border property to another color.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017777/change-color-of-window-frame), it solves your problem.